# UITextView has trouble scrolling down

Tags: ios, scroll, uitextview, xamarin

I have a UITextView in a Xamarin.ios app (on ios 7.0.6). When it has more text in it than can be visible at once it allows scrolling. If it is not already showing the text at the top, I can drag down with my finger to scroll up toward the top. If however I try the opposite (dragging up), most of the time it will not scroll down. It will reliably scroll down if I first drag down then up. What is going on (is this an apple bug)? Has anyone else observed this behavior? How can I improve it?

Comment: Do you mean, that the text is scrolled to the bottom at the very beginning?

Comment: No. Sorry my original post may be a bit confusing. All I meant to indicate was that the position before attempting to drag/scroll is neither at the top or bottom. So I would expect to be able to scroll in either direction. As I said, I can always scroll up, but only down if I first slightly scroll up in the same gesture.

Comment: Hmm good old scrollviews... f***ed us up in our project, too. Sometimes we had to set the Frame new like: `textView.Frame = textView.Frame`  after the view became visible.